# Datomic error creating connection Threadpoolbudget

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm trying out datomic for the first time, added the `[com.datomic/client-pro "0.8.28"]`
 dependency to my `project.clj` . I'm trying to connecting to the Client application. But this java error is thrown. What did I do wrong here ?

```
myapp.repl=> (require '[datomic.client.api :as d])
nil
myapp.repl=> (def cfg {:server-type :peer-server
           #_=> :access-key "myaccesskey"
           #_=> :secret "mysecret"
           #_=> :endpoint "localhost:8998"})
#'myapp.repl/cfg
myapp.repl=> (def client (d/client cfg))

CompilerException java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/ThreadPoolBudget, compiling:(form-init5680699117070720566.clj:1:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `NoClassDefFoundError` usually indicates a version mismatch due to dependency conflicts. In particular, I would suspect a transient dependency on a different version of Jetty than is required for the Datomic Client library.
You can use `lein deps :tree` to examine your dependency tree and identify what may be bringing in an earlier version of Jetty, which you can then exclude from that line in your `project.clj`.